# Подскажите, нужно ли здесь двоеточие

Tags: однородные-члены, двоеточие

Для него характерны (:) идеальная предметность, конструктивная однозначность, формальная доказательность и аналитическая проверяемость.

Ну и в подобных предложениях:

Для инженерно-технологического типа рациональности свойственны (:) «вещная» предметность, конструктивная системность, эмпирическая проверяемость, системная надежность, практическая эффективность.

Answer (score 1):

**3. Если однородным членам предложения не предшествует обобщающее слово (словосочетание), то перед ними двоеточие ставится только в том случае, когда необходимо предупредить читателя, что дальше следует перечисление:**

*Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и ещё какие-то привлекательные узелки и коробочки (Л. Т.); Тут были: Павел, чухонец, штабс-капитан Ярошевич, фельдфебель Максименко, красная фуражка, дама с белыми зубами, доктор (Ч.). Ср. в деловой и научной речи: На заседании присутствовали:…; Для получения смеси нужно взять:…; Роли исполняют:*… [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)

Answer (score 1):

Если **обобщающее слово** предшествует ряду однородных членов, то после обобщающего слова ставится двоеточие: *Рыбак-подледник бывает **разный:** рыбак-пенсионер, рыбак – рабочий и служащий, рыбак-военный, рыбак-министр, так сказать, государственный деятель, рыбак-интеллигент* (Сол.)
При обобщающих словах могут быть уточняющие слова **как например, например, как то, а именно**, перед которыми ставится запятая, а после них — двоеточие.
**Примечание.** В текстах деловых и научных двоеточие может ставиться перед перечислением и при отсутствии обобщающего слова.

[Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2/)

Ваши предложения носят явно научный характер, поэтому двоеточие можно использовать.

Вот пример из книги Ю. Лукаша "[Внутрифирменные конфликты, или Трудовая конфликтология в бизнесе](https://books.google.ee/books?id=AtSzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT142&lpg=PT142&dq=%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=PJppL9qJgU&sig=ACfU3U3ftkFEHWEFmDk-MnZzrKObMDWmqg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjajMvrj-rmAhXLlIsKHZgQBKcQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B&f=false)" (с двоеточием).
*В частности, различают следующие типы:

— **дистимный тип**, для него характерны: чрезвычайная серьезность, ответственность, сосредоточенность на мрачных мыслях, склонность к депрессии, низкая активность...*

Вот пример без двоеточия.
[Тревожный тип.] *Людям данного типа свойственны низкая контактность, минорное настроение, робость, пугливость, неуверенность в себе* (И. Сердюк. Социальная психология).

Answer (score 1):

В обоих предложениях следует поставить двоеточие:

*Для него характерны: **идеальная предметность, конструктивная однозначность, формальная доказательность и аналитическая проверяемость.***

Почему такой **однозначный** ответ?

Мы имеем однородный ряд подлежащих, стоящих после сказуемого в форме мн.числа (**обратный порядок слов**). При такой структуре **явно чувствуется отсутствие согласования в числе,** которое дополнительно подчеркивается наличием определения в ед.ч. (*характерны идеальная предметность*).

**Примечание:** При обратном порядке  слов  основной формой сказуемого считается ед.ч.,  и делается это именно для того, чтобы рядом стоящие  слова были согласованными. Однако это не наш случай, так как здесь подчеркивается множественность предметов, к тому же разнородных по смыслу.

И вот именно для того, чтобы **рассогласование не было очевидным**, перед однородным рядом делается пауза, которая заменяет пропущенное  обобщающее слово **следующие качества**.

Пауза обозначается **двоеточием.**